# Creating a dictionary using information from JSON file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file containing information as you can see in the attached file:
[Json File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2KzQL3L_VENXJZY0pVN2REdEE/view)

I need some help creating a "Dictionary of genres" for each *director* like this: *{GenreName: Number}* where "Number" corresponds to the amount of films belonging to that genre the director "created".

E.g. checking "Sidney Lumet" the dictionary should be like this:
*{u'Drama': 2, u'War': 1, u'Adventure': 1, u'Thriller': 2, u'Crime': 1}*

Since in the file you can read:

```
  "Before the Devil Knows You're Dead;2007": {
    "DIRECTORS": [
      "Sidney Lumet"
    ], 
    "GENRES": [
      "Crime", 
      "Drama", 
      "Thriller"
   "Fail-Safe;1964": {
    "DIRECTORS": [
      "Sidney Lumet"
    ], 
    "GENRES": [
      "Adventure", 
      "Drama", 
      "Thriller", 
      "War"
```

---

I explained wrongly what I needed in the title.
My problem isn't about how to retrieve the information (I know about the json module and I know how to access its elements), but I need help creating that particular dictionary for each director.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Comment: See pythons standard libraries, there is a fantastic json library

Comment: I'm already using the json library to access each element (Directors, Genres and ofc the title, what I'm not being able to do is creating that particular "genres" dictionary - my bad I wrote a wrong title).

Comment: Where does your data come from? Where do you store your data? In Python source (bad idea), from a file, from a database ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not python but algorithmic question. All related to pyhton here is

```
with open('file.json') as f:    
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then, you need go through all films and count each genre e.g. :

```
directors_dict = {}
for film_name, film in data.iteritems():
    for dir in film['DIRECTORS']:
        if not dir in directors_dict:
            directors_dict[dir] = {}
        for genr in film['GENRES']:
            if not genr in directors_dict[dir]:
                directors_dict[dir][genr] = 0
            directors_dict[dir][genr] += 1

 print(directors_dict)
```

PS: I am not tested this code, I even don't know exactly what format is (your file needs access from google drive). You should debug and correct mistakes using print() or debugger.

Comment: Yes you were right, anyways my question was both algorithmic and about python (I wasn't sure I could've been able to write the code in python by myself). Thanks!